# How to Save Data In tinymce Editor using mvc

Tags: tinymce

i have an application in which i integrate tinymce editor on that editor i have to save some data,how can i save it please guide me in proper way

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way to do it, but you will find a way [described here](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=11281).